# Nightly Excel Spreadheet import into mssql database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, insert, sql-server-2012

I am currently working with a nightly import that I need to create, but am not sure what the best route would be to update/insert into the current table.  This is all done in MS SQL Server 2012 and pulling the Excel file from another server.  I am trying to figure out how I can loop through the columns and pull out the data I need.  If I could rearrange the data, I would but am currently stuck with what I have.

In my current table tblHW I have Columns such as PmpCount, , NumberStages, Pmpmodel_pmp1, serialnum_Pmp1, pmpModel_pmp2, Pmpmodel_pmp2, serialnum_pmp2, partnum_motor1, serialnumberMotor1, etc….  I apologize in advance for not being able to post a real table or a picture.

Example:

```
|Name      | PmpCount| numstages| pmpmodel_pmp1| stages_pmp1| Sn_pmp1|
|AN 91-23G |        4|       500|        FX2347|         250|  354197|
|BR DN 895R|        5|       521|         D2442|          45|  875164|
|ALN 1-60J |        5|       521|        H21342|          95|  594126|

|pmpmodel_pmp2| stages_pmp2| sn_pmp2| Partnum_mtr1| sn_mtr1|
|FX2347       |         250|  354198|         NULL|    NULL|
|FX17500      |         143|  102547|        M7544| 4512241|
|FX17500      |         143|  458790|        M7544| 4512364|
```

The information I want to move into tblHW comes from the tbl Pull_Down.  Here is the setup:

```
|Name      | Run_ID               | Part1| SN1     |    Attribute1_7|
|AN 21-919G| Oct 08, 2013 / 100845|   BOD|       NA|           3RD U|
|FR 55-013A| Oct 17, 2013 / 100853|   Pmp| 2EA3A022|              78|
|FR 55-013A| Oct 01, 2014 / 101383|   Cbl|      N/A|        REDALEAD|
|FR 43-223J| Apr 03, 2013 / 100594|   BOD|       NA|           3RD U|
|VH 204    | May 17, 2014 / 101145|   BOD|    3RD U|



|Part2| SN2      | Attribute2_7| Part3   | SN3     | Attribute3_7|
|Pmp  |  2EA3F379|           78|      Pmp| 2EA3N380|          117|
|Pmp  |  2EA3C020|          117|      Pmp| 2EA3Y021|          117|
|MLE  | J14312161|          120|      BOD|      N/A|        3RD U|
|Other|        NA|          Pmp| 2EA2X774|       78|
|BOD  |      NULL|          Pmp| 2EA4F075|       38|
```

A bit more information.  I am receiving this information in the form of five excel spreadhsheets each with over 400 columns.  The columns giving me the biggest headache are the 20 part columns that I need to place into the SQL table.

I need to somehow move each row into the tblHW but need to do something like this:

The first row AN 21-919G needs to have SN1 to be inserted into sn_mtr1 since it is a BOD, SN2 into SN_pmp1 since it is a PMP, and SN3 into sn_pmp2 since it is the second PMP here.  I also need to get the pmp count, in this case 2 and then add the attribute1_7 and attribute2_7 to put into numstages when the prts are PMP.

Comment: I'm no expert, but perhaps I can give you a high level plan. You either format your data before it's in SQL Server or after. If you want to format then put it in, I'd bet an SSIS solution would be your best bet. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with SSIS. On the other hand, if you want to do it in SQL. I'd create some staging tables just to hold the raw excel data and then write your queries accordingly to update the other table(s). Hope this helps. If you need help writing queries, I'm sure someone if not me can help you there. I'd also recommend trying the DBA stackexchange site. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Situations like this is the whole purpose for SSIS to exist: Integration Services!

First one would question as to why the data you need is in Excel, and if there is a more direct route, one could exploit, as a linked server (if the source is another RDBMS).

Based in what information you provide, we make the following assumptions:
A) We have no control on the source output and we must import the data from Excel.
B) The files always have consistent columns (probably created by an automated process).

In SSIS you can easily create a source connection for the Excel file. If the Excel file name is dynamic, you can create a script to modify the connection string for that connection before importing data. Then set the destination connection to the SQL Server. The last step is creating a Data Flow Task where you can map the source to the destination columns.

Example:
[image]

Comment: +1 for warning about Excel, worst migraines of my life have come from dealing with Excel in SSIS.  Get it into a flat file anyway you can.